# How to direct alternating measures of 6/8 and 5/8 time signatures?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, conducting

This is a allegro piece eighth note = 204 and alternates measures from 6/8 and 5/8. My question is how to direct this? The 6/8 would be in two. Would the 5/8 also be in two with the next 6/8 measure coming earlier?

Comment: I've never conducted but if I saw alternating 6/8 and 5/8 I'd read it as compound time in two with a dropped eighth note every other measure.

Answer (score 5):

Study the 5/8 measure and determine the subdivision.  Commonly, it'll be 2+3/8 or 3+2/8.  For conducting, you'll treat 5/8 like a 6/8 pattern, but dropping the appropriate 8th notes to match the subdivision.